# Suppose that characteristic $F$ is $p$. If $K/F$ is separable then $K = F(K^{p})$ where $K^{p} = \{ x^{p} \, |\, x\in K\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am having difficulty finishing this problem.  So far I have this:

Want to show $K \subset F(K^{p})$.  Since $K/F$ is separable then $K/F$ is algebraic.  In particular, $\alpha\in K$ is separable over $F$ hence separable over $F(\alpha^{p})$.  So $\alpha\in F(\alpha^{p})$ by an exercise already done.  But then I do not know how to conclude $\alpha\in F(K^{p})$. Any suggestions?  Or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: Why doesn't $\alpha \in F(\alpha^p)$ immediately imply $\alpha \in F(K^p)$? After all, $\alpha^p \in K^p$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L=F(K^p)$. Clearly, we have $F\subseteq L\subseteq K$. It is also clear that for every $\alpha\in K$, we have $\alpha^p\in L$. This shows that the extension $K/L$ is purely inseparable ([see characterization 2 here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_inseparable_extension#Purely_inseparable_extensions)). But $K/F$ separable implies that $K/L$ is separable ([see the second bullet here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_extension#Properties)) and because $K/L$ is both separable and purely inseparable, we have $K=L$.